# Подскажите что поправить в коде задачи про массивы

Tags: java, массивы

Дана задача - Cоздать двумерный массив из 7 строк по 4 столбца в каждой из случайных целых чисел из отрезка [-5;5]. Вывести массив на экран. Определить и вывести на экран индекс строки с наибольшим по модулю произведением элементов. Если таких строк несколько, то вывести индекс первой встретившейся из них.

```
public class Les56TwoMas74 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] mas=new int[7][4];
        int max=0;
        int max_i=0;
        int[] mas1=new int[mas.length];
        for(int i=0;i<mas.length;i++){
            System.out.print("Cтрока № "+i+" ");
            for(int j = 0;j<mas[i].length;j++){
                mas[i][j]= (int) (Math.random()*11-5);
                System.out.print(mas[i][j]+"\t");
                if(j==0){
                    mas1[i]=mas[i][j];
                }else{
                    mas1[i]*=mas[i][j];
                }if(j==mas[i].length-1){
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }
        }for(int i=0;i<mas1.length;i++){
            if(Math.abs(mas1[i]>max)){
                max=mas1[i];
                max_i=i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Строка с наибольшим по модулю произведением элементов ("+max+") имеет индекс - "+max_i);
    }
}
```

Подскажите как поправить код. Заранее спасибо за помощь)

P.S. Через поисковик по сайту не нашел данную задачу, возможно она есть, неуверен - недавно на сайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы применяли Math.abs() к выражения сравнения, то есть вы хотели сделать что-то вроде этого: Math.abs(true), из-за этого ошибка и вылетала, применяя модуль к каждому значению по отдельности ошибки быть не должно

```
 }for(int i=0;i<mas1.length;i++){
                if(Math.abs(mas1[i])>Math.abs(max)){
                    max=mas1[i];
                    max_i=i;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Внес вашу правку в код - пришлось в строку вывода результата так же Math.abs(max) добавить иначе выводил и положительные и отрицательные числа